# Conditionally hiding form fields in Access

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm building a database for work to book in computer repairs. I'm trying to make an 'Open Jobs' continuous form. The form will contain fields - JobID, EntryDate, Forename, Surname and JobStatus.

The Forename and Surname will be joined - `=[Forename] & ' ' & [Surname]`

JobStatus refers to a lookup field in my JobStatusT table. Each status has a JobStatusID ranging from 1-4.

What I am trying to achieve is, when JobStatus = 4 or Collected all fields for that record should not be visible.

Comment: Look up conditional formatting.

Comment: I've seen a lot about that but apparently conditional formatting doesn't allow visible false

Comment: While that is true, you can set the fields that they are not enabled, and that the text colour is the same as the background colour, which is nearly invisible.

Comment: That is also something that I have seen, however, I have a backup of the database my old place used to use and that one uses a continuous without any conditionals and yet it seems to completely hide the fields for the relevant record. I can upload a copy of the database used by my old work place if anyone can deconstruct it and figure it out

Comment: Bump, anyone? Please